# How to receive a message, instead of throwing exception in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I have a function for displaying the user bag in e-commenrce website. When the user bag is empty, it throws the following exception:

```
if (!$bag) {
    throw  new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

How can i display a message like "Your bag is empty", or something, instead of throwing an

> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it.

You can use [flash messages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages) or even [render twig template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#rendering-templates) that will inform about empty bag.

Or you can pass to template the parameter that will say that bag is empty and then you can use that parameter in the template.

Or you can check `$bag` object right in twig template like

`{% if bag is null %}Your bag is empty{% endif %}`

Comment: Flash messages are exactly for that purpose.